# can we display html page which we deployed on to azure functions app

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

Can we display html page which we deployed on to azure function app along with .js and .json files. Could any one suggest please.

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.body) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + req.body.fname +req.body.lname
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Here is an example of an HTTPTrigger function which returns HTML:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
        context.done();

    } else {

        // Read an HTML file in the directory and return the contents
        fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'), 'UTF-8', (err, htmlContent) => {
            context.res = {
                headers: {"Content-Type": "text/html"},
                body: htmlContent
            };

            context.done();
        });

    }
};
```