# How to run HTML at runtime in C# using azure function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

I have a file XHTMLTemplate.cs which is as follows:

```
namespace sqlicmalertfunctionsapp
{
    public class XHTMLTemplates
    {
        public static string GenerateXHTMLDescriptionFromAppLogs(List<TableData> transfers)
        {
            string description = "<html>"
                            + "<head> <style> "
                            + "table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
                            + "th td { font-weight: bold; }"
                            + "th, td { padding: 5px; text-align: left; }"
                            + "</style> </head>"
                            + "<body>"
                            + "<div> "
                            + "<h2 style=\"color: #fff; margin: 0; background-color: #6495ed\"> Table Name </h2>"
                            + "<br/>"
                            + "<table>"
                                + "<tr>"
                                    + "<th> CustomerNbr </th>"
                                    + "<th> CustomerName </th>"
                                    + "<th> MSOrderNumber </th>"
                                    + "<th> Quantity </th>"
                                    + "<th> PromoQuantity </th>"
                                    + "<th> QtyDiff </th>"
                                    + "<th> NetAmount </th>"
                                    + "<th> PromoNetAmount </th>"
                                    + "<th> AmtDiff </th>"
                                    + "<th> ExtendedAmount </th>"
                                    + "<th> PromoExtendedAmount </th>"
                                    + "<th> isICMSent </th>"
                                + "</tr>"
                                + string.Join(" ",
                                transfers.Select(t => (
                               "<tr>"
                               + $"<td> {t.CustomerNbr} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.CustomerName} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.MSOrderNumber} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.Quantity} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.PromoQuantity} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.QtyDiff} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.NetAmount} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.PromoNetAmount} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.AmtDiff} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.ExtendedAmount} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.PromoExtendedAmount} </td>"
                               + $"<td> {t.isICMSent} </td>"
                               + "</tr>"
                               )))
                            + "</table>"
                            + "</div>"
                            + "</body>"
                            + "</html>";
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a time triggered azure function which pushes table rows to this template at runtime and gives a string of html file. How to display this string using azure function? Are there any other alternatives of displaying HTML code using azure function?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example script for adding HTML script as an attachment and running timer triggered function.

```
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Http.Headers;  
  
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)  
{  
log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");  
  
string html = @"<html>  
<head><title>Hello world!</title></head>  
<body>  
<h1>Hello World!</h1>  
<p>from my <strong>Azure Function</strong></p>  
</body>  
</html>";  
  
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);  
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));  
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")  
{ FileName = "file.html" };  
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");  
  
return result;  
}  
}
```

Here are the related links:

1. [Return HTML or file content from C# Azure function.](https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/return-html-file-content-c-azure-function/%29)
2. [C# Azure functions separate html and css.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355106/how-to-return-html-file-in-http-response-azure-functions%29)
3. [Can we display html page which we deployed on to Azure function app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264644/can-we-display-html-page-which-we-deployed-on-to-azure-functions-app%29)